# Phonegap Torch for IOS refuses to compile

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Hey I'm trying to make the phone gap IOS work together with [the Torch plugin.](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/Torch)
The cordova app(2.1.0) ready was displaying before i proceeded with the torch plugin installation.

Though now i get an error when trying to compile it. I know absolutely nothing about IOS developing, so I'm pleading you guys for help. Here is a screenshot of the errors in the Torch.h:

[image: error]

Also errors in Torch.m:

[image: errors2] 
Screenshot of package explorer:

[image: package explorer]

after using Elio' .h changes it resulted in it compiling, but .m file is now giving these errors:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the preprocessor macro of the torch plugin, anyway saw that you use cordova 2.1.0 you can remove this part on the plugin : try [this](https://github.com/ElioDantoni/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/Torch).

Comment: I can remove which part? Isn't that the exact thing I have used already?

Comment: did you try? or just asking before?

Comment: Omg sorry, didn't see it was your repo, I'll try later today or tomorrow. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Tested it, .h compiles fine now, but some errors remain in the .m file, i uploaded a picture with these. Hope you can fix them as well. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Ok try again I've modified the .m

Answer (score 1):

I've written a torch plugin for Cordova 2.2.0.  You cn find it here:

https://github.com/tomschreck/iOS-Torch-Plugin